# Android: How to access a file in the SD Card

Tags: android, android-sdcard, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to access the image on the SD card using below code but I"m getting File not found exception. Can someone tell me a correct way to acess the file???

```
new File("/mnt/sdcard/splah2.jpg")
```

Comment: Have you added proper permissions in AndroidManifest file ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try like this:

```
String SD_CARD_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
new File(SD_CARD_PATH + "/" + "splah2.jpg");
```

Comment: OMG!!!! wot a shame, dat was a silly spelling mistake in file name :) thanks for saving my day :)

Comment: External storage doesn't always mean it's SD card. Some manufacturers reserve a space in the built-in internal storage which can acts as a "external storage". Read thoroughly the [official definition here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

Answer (score 3):

Try running: `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/splah2.jpg")`

Comment: @Mayu may be because file is not there where you are looking for it

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
File f=new File("/sdcard/splah2.jpg");
```

Comment: Don't do that. Try to never use a hard coded path to access the external memory.

Answer (score 0):

The code below has worked for me.

```
String mRelativeFolderPath = "/DCIM/Camera/";  // i.e. SDCard/DCIM/Camera
String mBaseFolderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + mRelativeFolderPath; 
String filePath = mBaseFolderPath  + "test.jpg";
File handle = new File(filePath);
```

Shash

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    new File("/sdcard/splah2.jpg")
```

or

```
    new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "splah2.jpg")
```

both are same if SD card is install because,

```
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns "/sdcard"
```