# FileNotFoundException in java

Tags: java, android, file-io, exception, filenotfoundexception

I'm developing a simple android application which needs a text file access! I'm getting `filenotfoundexception` even though I specified the absolute path of the file in File constructor. My code is

```
`File fr = new File("C:/mywork1/Dictionary/src/com/praveen/dictionary/vsn.txt");
                System.out.println(fr.getAbsolutePath());
                Scanner bb = new Scanner(fr);
                System.out.println(fr.exists());
                while((strf = bb.nextLine()) != null)
                {...
```

Some previous questions have answers that suggest using `AssetsManager` instead. I tried that.

```
AssetManager assetManager = Context.getAssets();
InputStream in = null;
in = assetManager.open("vsn.txt");
```

the error I'm getting for this code is

> "cannot make static reference to a non static variable"

At the first line. Kindly help me out with this problem.. I can't even use throws clause since I'm using onCreate method! I changed the settings in the run configuration so that current working directory will contain my text file. Thanks

Comment: Why did you think an Android device has a `C` unit to begin with?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza :D +1. Amazing mistake

Comment: Try `AssetManager assetManager = yourContextObject.getAssets();`

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh that's not an excuse to use `C` unit in code.

Comment: Android is not .... You know..

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: wanted to specify the absolute path.. That's my drive name!I tried this out of curiosity..anyways ,even if i specify only filename i get the same error. Suggest any changes in absolute path.

Comment: Even in Windows, you should not use the disk unit to refer for absolute paths. You should use `/an/absolute/path/like/this` instead, the JVM in Windows will handle the unit where the application is running (`C`, `D`, etc).

Comment: @PankajKumar: I need a suggestion for my question!!!

Comment: @NarasimhanVs Use The [Environment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) class of Android Framework. There are methods which can help you to access like the external storage. Please read it!

Comment: Please first let us know where is this *vsn.txt* file: inside your project/application resources? inside the Android device? inside an external storage sd card?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Its inside my src folder where other java files are kept!Should i keep it under resources? If yes where in resources directory i should place the file?

Comment: @NarasimhanVs Put that file in `asset` directory not in `src` and, refer to @ZouZou's answer to retrieve that file at runtime .

Comment: @ZouZou: i tried that in my code specified above! what is "yourContextObject"? I used Context.. Im getting the error as specified..

Comment: @NarasimhanVs If you don't have a contextObject and you're in a class that extends activity, you could use `getActivity().getAssets();`

Comment: @system32: yes it tried that. I used Context as my contextobject and im getting "cannot make static reference to a non static variable"..

Comment: I solved.. I used AssetManager and BufferedReader!! Thanks to Everyone who helped me...

Answer (score 2):

An Android device wont save or read to a file that is in a C: Directory.

You have to move it into your Resources folder within the project and include it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Android is based on Linux and therefore doesn't use a filesystem with drive letters like `c:\` etc.

If you want to open a file it depends where it is. If you have it in your assets directory you use the `AssetsManager`. The reason why you can do it the way you tried is because you call the method on the class and not the object. If the code is in an `Activity` simply do:

```
getAssets().open("vsn.txt");
```

in a Fragment do:

```
getActivity().getAssets().open("vsn.txt");
```

If you want access to the external files directory call `getExternalFilesDir(null)` on your `Context` object.

Answer (score 0):

Use the external storage sd card to file creation and deletion..
Use standard Java I/O. Use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to get to the root of external storage (which, on some devices, is an SD card).

below is a function that will programmatically move your file

set the correct permissions in the manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


private void moveFile(String inputPath, String inputFile, String outputPath) {

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {

        //create output directory if it doesn't exist
        File dir = new File (outputPath); 
        if (!dir.exists())
        {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }


        in = new FileInputStream(inputPath + inputFile);        
        out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + inputFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;

            // write the output file
            out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;

        // delete the original file
        new File(inputPath + inputFile).delete();  


    } 

         catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
        Log.e("tag", fnfe1.getMessage());
    }
          catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

To Delete the file use

```
private void deleteFile(String inputPath, String inputFile) {
    try {
        // delete the original file
        new File(inputPath + inputFile).delete();  


    }
   catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
        Log.e("tag", fnfe1.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

To copy

```
private void copyFile(String inputPath, String inputFile, String outputPath) {

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {

        //create output directory if it doesn't exist
        File dir = new File (outputPath); 
        if (!dir.exists())
        {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }


        in = new FileInputStream(inputPath + inputFile);        
        out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + inputFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;

            // write the output file (You have now copied the file)
            out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;        

    }  catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
        Log.e("tag", fnfe1.getMessage());
    }
            catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: i need a simple text file for my dictionary program! Wats the part of sdcard in it? Y cant i simply make modifications to the code i specified to get the desired result? I kept my text file inside src folder which contain other java files.. Is that ri8?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your text file @sdcard or @assets folder in android application. To access file from sdcard is mention  [Android: How to access a file in the SD Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102104/android-how-to-access-a-file-in-the-sd-card) & to access file from assests folder mention in this link [Android - Access file from assets \ PDF display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980852/android-access-file-from-assets-pdf-display)