# Is there anybody can help me ? I want to choose some sound ( anywhere in the phone) and send information of this sound to another Activity to play it

Tags: android

I have no idea about choosing a audio file .mp3 , wma...  in sd card (That's in the Setting Activity and send the sound to the Main activity for playing it by user).
And what kind of information (of this sound ) can i send to Main activity to play it? 
.I'm sorry, but my 'reputation' is too low to post a picture.
Thanks.

Comment: First, please frame question properly. Atleast, use proper English and remove these extra (...) and (???).

Now to your question, if I am not getting it wrong you need a default sound for your app you can store any sound/video or any other file in res/raw directory and then reference it.

Comment: Sorry ,i just want to choose file in sd card ( in the Setting Activity) and send the sound to the Main activity for playing it by user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Here you go

Set the path of file like this-

```
String SD_CARD_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

new File(SD_CARD_PATH + "/" + "your_file_name.mp3");
```

Code from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102104/android-how-to-access-a-file-in-the-sd-card)

and use android [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) to play the song.

```
public void playSong(String file_path){
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try{
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file_path);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know exactly my file :( "your_file_name.mp3"), because the user  will choose it from their phone. I'm looking for a  brouser, might be.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856959/android-file-chooser

Comment: Thanks a lots @Amit . I've built one. But, when i get the file (path). how can i play it ?

Comment: edited the answer. see it ^

Comment: I found it in google. But thanks. :) .